# In the Arduino IDE, why does the second call of a function change the previous call results?

Tags: function, utf-8, arduino

I tried to write a function that converts a string of hex values into a string of Unicode UTF-8 characters. When this function is called once, everything is fine. But when the function is called twice in succession with the same or different arguments, both output strings are meaningless.

```cpp
void HEX2String(String* HEXstr, String* str) {
  String s2 = "", s3 = "";
  long c, c1, c0;
  char ch[2] = { 0 };
  for (int i = 0; i <= HEXstr->length() - 4; i = i + 4) {
    s2 = HEXstr->substring(i, i + 1) + "x" + HEXstr->substring(i + 1, i + 4);
    c = (hex2long(&s2));
    if (c < 255)
      *str += String((char)c);
    else {
      c1 = (128 + (c & B111111));
      c0 = (192 + (c >> 6));
      ch[1] = c1;
      ch[0] = c0;
      str->concat(ch);
    }
  }
}

String str1 = "0628064700200646062706450020062E062F0627000A0633064406270645000A064806310648062F0020062806470020063306CC0633062A06450020062A064806330637";
String str = "0628064700200646062706450020062E062F0627000A0633064406270645000A064806310648062F0020062806470020063306CC0633062A06450020062A064806330637000A00730061006C0061006D0020006200610072002000730068006F006D0061";
String msg = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //First call
  HEX2String(&str, &msg);
  Serial.println(msg);
  msg = "";
  //Second call
  HEX2String(&str1, &msg);
  Serial.println(msg);
}

void main() {
  //
}
```

If I comment the second call, the output in the serial monitor is:

```
سلام
ورود به سیستم توسط
salam bar shoma
```

It is correct. If the second call is not commented, the output in the serial monitor is:

```
ب⸮⸮ه⸮⸮ ن⸮⸮ا⸮⸮م⸮⸮ خ⸮⸮د⸮⸮ا⸮⸮
س⸮⸮ل⸮⸮ا⸮⸮م⸮⸮
و⸮⸮ر⸮⸮و⸮⸮د⸮⸮ ب⸮⸮ه⸮⸮ س⸮⸮ی⸮⸮س⸮⸮ت⸮⸮م⸮⸮ ت⸮⸮و⸮⸮س⸮⸮ط⸮⸮
salam bar shomaب⸮⸮ه⸮⸮ ن⸮⸮ا⸮⸮م⸮⸮ خ⸮⸮د⸮⸮ا⸮⸮
س⸮⸮ل⸮⸮ا⸮⸮م⸮⸮
و⸮⸮ر⸮⸮و⸮⸮د⸮⸮ ب⸮⸮ه⸮⸮ س⸮⸮ی⸮⸮س⸮⸮ت⸮⸮م⸮⸮ ت⸮⸮و⸮⸮س⸮⸮ط⸮⸮
```

Comment: It looks like @dda repaired some case and grammar errors in the title. You appear to have added them back in again, so I have repaired it. Please do not revert that - little improvements from volunteer editors are a favour to you.

Comment: [If an answer solved your problem, you should accept it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Don't add a "Thank you" as an answer or add "*(Solved)*" to the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-strings need to be null terminated. Your `ch` is not.

Define it as 3 characters:

```cpp
char ch[3] = { 0 };
```

and add a null terminator:

```cpp
ch[0] = c0;
ch[1] = c1;
ch[2] = 0;
```